# JSON array of length 1 sent to MVC method is null, 2+ is fine

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I've got a webpage that sends information to an MVC method via AJAX call. The call looks exactly like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: "post",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify({ model: model }),
   success: function (result) {
      if (result == "ok") {
         u.setMessage("Reloading");
         window.location.reload();
      }
      else {
         var text = result == "long" ? "Episode Name is too long." : "";
         notify(false, text);
      }
   },
   error: function () {
      notify(false);
      u.stop();
   }
});
```

Within the model object that I said, there is field called "Episodes". If I only send one episode to my controller method, the Episodes field is null. My web console debugger tells me that I am indeed populating the episodes field like this:

```
"Episodes":[{"ReleaseYear":"2020","Name":"series episode 0e3","EpisodeNumber":"0e3","SeasonId"
:"9202"}]
```

However, if I add an additional entry into the Episodes field, my controller method's object will show an Episodes array with two objects in it.

```
"Episodes":[{"ReleaseYear":"2015","Name":"series episode     800a1","EpisodeNumber":"800a1"
,"SeasonId":"9202"},{"ReleaseYear":"2015","Name":"series episode 800a2","EpisodeNumber":"800a2"
,"SeasonId":"9202"}]
```

Why would my controller method detect the field when it has multiple objects as opposed to just one? I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: sounds like problem is in your controller not in how you are sending the data

Comment: Why would you not post your controller code for this question?